# display result of max() function with imshow in opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I have 2 Mat of 1 image with a little differences in some pixels. I want to find max for each pixel and show them. I wrote this code in Visual C++ 2010 (Console):

```
Mat dst;
max(result0, result1, dst);
imshow("dst", dst);
```

and the dst image was displayed perfectly, but when I copied this code in windows form I received this error: "error C2440: '?' : cannot convert from 'cv::MatExpr' to 'bool'" so I changed the code to this:

```
Mat dst;
max(&result0, &result1, &dst);
imshow("dst", dst);
```

but in run time this error was appeared:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in OpenCVProject.exe
Additional information: External component has thrown an exception."

please help me to display the image.
thanks in advance

Comment: Are the size and type of result0 and result1 the same ?

Comment: yes, infact I created both of them with filter2D on source image

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem.And I find it is the minwindef.h that result in this problem.so you can add this：

```
#undef max
#undef min
```

below in the header files（#include<...>）,and then you can use cv::max successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is namespaces conflict.
Try specify namespace as below:

cv::max

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Now there is 2 more errors: "error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'" and "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'"

Comment: You can try use C API's function cvMax, but first you have to convert cv::Mat to IplImage* .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by dekai adding the below but after the using namespace headers worked for me

```
#undef max
#undef min
```